# What is the difference between hCaptcha and reCAPTCHA?

Tags: python, html, selenium, recaptcha, hcaptcha

I work with python selenium, and I wanted to know what is the difference between hCaptcha and reCAPTCHA?
So what I discovered is that all sites that work with `Cloudflare` support `hCaptcha` and not `reCAPTCHA` and I wanted to know if it is possible to pass `hCaptcha` like other people pass `reCAPTCHA`. Like in this video [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5puz9Mb2d_c) that explains how to pass `reCAPTCHA`, and I asked myself if it is possible to do the same on hCaptcha and if the code that the guy writes on YouTube, might work on `hCaptcha`.
(I thought maybe I could copy the code and try it myself, but who knows, maybe I didn't succeed because it actually sounds like there is a difference between `hCaptcha` and reCAPTCHA, and I didn't find any information on the Internet on how to pass `hCaptcha` as well, and maybe you can tell me how I can pass hCaptcha like `reCAPTCHA` or not! )

hCaptcha image that is:
[hCaptcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5rYd.png)

Comment: Yes it's similar, some people are moving to hcaptcha because of recaptcha price increase

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : In regards to hCaptch this might help ?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfNczYvSp3k&ab_channel=MichaelKitas

General Difference

Basically reCAPTCHA and hCaptcha are both similar & popular CAPTCHA. reCAPTCHA is owned and operated by Google while hCaptcha is an independent CAPTCHA provider (parent company is an image labeling company).

reCAPTCHA has versions like  reCAPTCHA v2 (typically checking a checkbox or solving image challenge etc),  reCAPTCHA v3 (score-based system based on user interaction - works on the background) & blocks basic bot traffic
reCAPTCHA gathers more data than it should.
(Has a free “Publisher” version)

On the other hand, hCaptcha - unlike reCaptcha they have a strict privacy policy that aims to minimize data collection and ensure user privacy & capthca Challenges are more difficult.
(Isn’t free if you want the best features)